# I have an image slideshow on my homepage but when I go to other page it throws an error

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a website page and image slideshow on it:

```
<div className="recommended" id="bluelakes">
   <p className="greeting-text">We also recommend you visiting <span>Blue Lakes</span>:</p>
   <div className="recommended-brief">
      <div className="description">
         <p>
            <span className="dark">Ecological trail "<span>Blue Lakes</span>"</span>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            is located on the territory of the Narochansky National Park in the Myadel district, 500 m beyond the village of Olshevo.
            <br/>
            <br/>
            Each time you come to this amazing place, you will discover something new, this is a unique hilly-lake complex with vast forests, an abundance of springs and truly unique lakes.
        </p>
    </div>
        <div className="carousel">
            <div className="carousel-item first">
                <img id="slide" alt="slide"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="more">
            <a href="/" className="see-more">See more...</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

And this is the slideshow script itself:

```
import bluelakesFirst from '../media/images/BlueLakes/BlueLakes1.jpg'
import bluelakesSecond from '../media/images/BlueLakes/BlueLakes2.jpg'
import bluelakesThird from '../media/images/BlueLakes/BlueLakes3.jpg'
import bluelakesFourth from '../media/images/BlueLakes/BlueLakes4.jpg'

let n = 0;
let images = [];

images[0] = bluelakesFirst
images[1] = bluelakesSecond
images[2] = bluelakesThird
images[3] = bluelakesFourth

let switchImage = () => {
    document.getElementById('slide').src = images[n]

    if (n < images.length - 1) {
        n++;
    } else {
        n = 0;
    }

    setTimeout(switchImage, 3000);
}

window.onload = switchImage
```

It works properly, but when I go to **About us** page or any other, it throws an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null
switchImage

D:/trail.by/src/scripts/carousel.js:15
  12 | images[3] = bluelakesFourth
  13 | 
  14 | let switchImage = () => {
> 15 |     document.getElementById('slide').src = images[n]
  16 | 
  17 |     if (n < images.length - 1) {
  18 |         n++;
```

I understand it is so probably because other pages do not have an element with this ID, but I haven't imported this script on other pages either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap that snippet of code in `if` statement.

```
if(document.getElementById('slide') !== null) {
   document.getElementById('slide').src = images[n]
}
```